# How to access a subset of values from the returned set of values of a function in Python?

Tags: python

I have a Python function that returns a set of values say `a1,...,an`.

*Example.* The returned set is a1,a2,a3,a4.

```
def myFunction():
    # The code
    return a1,a2,a3,a4
```

I would like to access only `a1` and `a4` for example, how?

I tried

```
a1, , ,a4 = myFunction()
```

but it gives me error `too many to unpack`

EDIT The error `too many to unpack`was only given when I tried `a1,=myFunction()`

Comment: Which version(s) of Python? `a1, *_, a4 = ...` works in 3.x.

Comment: Python 2.7 with anaconda.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was looking for that (duplicate) question but I couldn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
a1, _, _,a4 = myFunction()
```

using `_` is a common convention in *Python* for variables that are likely not to be used; they are still variables though.

Comment: Other option is just `result = myFunction()` then reference by place in the tuple `result[0]`

Comment: Sure; but it all depends on whether OP has enough patience to do `result[0]` & `result[3]` or not.

Comment: Thank you. It works. The system says "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes"